# C++-Build: After editing a file in a project the build process takes a long time. How to find out which files/classes are responsible?

Tags: c++, time, build, compilation

I have a very large VC++-Project which takes a long time to Rebuild after i edited a file. Maybe it's a central-class and so the following classes have to be rebuild, too. I'm using class-definitions and do include the header in the cpp-file, not .h-file in .h-file ;-)

Is there a way to find out which class/file is resposible? Are some useful tools to visualize the includes in a graph/dependencygraph? How do you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any file which directly or indirectly (through another include) #includes the file you changed will have to be rebuilt.  Also if you have custom rules (say, the file you are editing is part of a custom rule that generates new source files), then any files changed by this rule and their dependencies will also have to be rebuilt.

MSDN Doc for visualizing the dependency graph:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657798.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[ElectricAccelerator](http://www.electric-cloud.com/eade) can help you answer this question by giving you an XML-annotated build log that includes information about which files are accessed during the compilation of each object, and the build time for each object.  It has a Visual Studio plugin so it integrates right into your current environment.

*Disclaimer: I'm the architect of ElectricAccelerator*